# Android app coded in python crashes after splashscreen and logcat gives errors

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I coded an Android app in Python with the kivy library and compiled it with buildozer. When I opened it on an Android phone, it crashes after the splashscreen. This is the logcat error. What is the issue?

```
2023-05-08 19:40:29.663 12397-12431 bt_btif                 pid-12397                            E  HAL bt_hf_callbacks->UnknownAtCallback
2023-05-08 19:40:31.123  1297-4126  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  ThreadHelper: thread_callback() 145: More than one pending updates!!! This should not happen. MeterMgr should avoid this case.
2023-05-08 19:40:31.127  1297-1330  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-05-08 19:40:31.127  1297-1330  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-05-08 19:40:31.127  1717-3232  ANDR-PERF-JNI           pid-1717                             E  com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
2023-05-08 19:40:31.130  1294-4158  ANDR-IOP                pid-1294                             E  io prefetch is disabled
2023-05-08 19:40:31.171  1297-1330  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-05-08 19:40:31.172  1297-4126  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  ThreadHelper: thread_callback() 145: More than one pending updates!!! This should not happen. MeterMgr should avoid this case.
2023-05-08 19:40:31.233  1297-1330  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-05-08 19:40:31.290   666-666   aspersonalesapp         pid-666                              E  Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2023-05-08 19:40:31.378   666-666   SurfaceSyncer           pid-666                              E  Failed to find sync for id=0
2023-05-08 19:40:31.432  1297-4126  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  ThreadHelper: thread_callback() 145: More than one pending updates!!! This should not happen. MeterMgr should avoid this case.
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=0
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=1
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=2
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=3
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=4
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=5
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=6
2023-05-08 19:40:31.482 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=7
2023-05-08 19:40:31.501   729-729   audit                   pid-729                              E  rate limit exceeded
2023-05-08 19:40:31.654  1375-1375  CompositionEngine       pid-1375                             E  [PipMenuView#148184] Invalid device requested composition type change: Client (1) --> Client (1)
2023-05-08 19:40:31.742 12397-12468 bt_btif                 pid-12397                            E  2c:be:eb:06:a6:f5
2023-05-08 19:40:31.742 12397-12431 bt_btif                 pid-12397                            E  HAL bt_hf_callbacks->UnknownAtCallback
2023-05-08 19:40:31.757   702-21334 android.sy....0-service pid-702                              E  Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup136 (../../devices/platform/soc/soc:qcom,msm-audio-apr/soc:qcom,msm-audio-apr:qcom,q6core-audio/soc:qcom,msm-audio-apr:qcom,q6core-audio:sound/Listen 2 Audio Service/wakeup/wakeup136): Permission denied
2023-05-08 19:40:31.761   702-21334 android.sy....0-service pid-702                              E  Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup32 (../../devices/platform/soc/984000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0020/wakeup/wakeup32): Permission denied
2023-05-08 19:40:32.148  1297-4093  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  VmRssMeter:: start() 453: Could not find pid, can not collect vmrss data
2023-05-08 19:40:32.148  1297-4093  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  AdaptiveLaunch: writeToDataBase() 64: Meter aborted or could not get meter data for this run
2023-05-08 19:40:32.149  1297-4092  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  VmRssMeter:: start() 453: Could not find pid, can not collect vmrss data
2023-05-08 19:40:32.287  1375-1375  BpTransact...edListener pid-1375                             E  Failed to transact (-32)
2023-05-08 19:40:32.374  1297-4121  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  StatsProvider: stats_nl_error_callback() 115: NL SOC receive error: No such process
2023-05-08 19:40:32.374  1297-4121  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  StatsProvider: sendRecvData() 272: nl_recvmsgs failed return=-12
2023-05-08 19:40:32.374  1297-4121  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  StatsProvider: getPIDStats() 124: sendRecvData returned error = -4
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=0
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=1
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=2
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=3
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=4
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=5
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=6
2023-05-08 19:40:32.639 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=7
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=0
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=1
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=2
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=3
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=4
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=5
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=6
2023-05-08 19:40:32.655 20035-20035 SurfaceSyncer           pid-20035                            E  Failed to find sync for id=7
2023-05-08 19:40:32.674  1297-4121  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  StatsProvider: stats_nl_error_callback() 115: NL SOC receive error: No such process
2023-05-08 19:40:33.233  1297-1329  ANDR-PERF-UTIL          pid-1297                             E  Failed to update node /proc/666/sched_boost with value 0
2023-05-08 19:40:33.234  1297-1329  ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER   pid-1297                             E  can't reset task 666
2023-05-08 19:40:33.234  1297-1329  ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS    pid-1297                             E  Failed to reset optimization [3, 32]
2023-05-08 19:40:33.275  1297-4121  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  StatsProvider: stats_nl_error_callback() 115: NL SOC receive error: No such process
2023-05-08 19:40:33.309  1297-4093  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  VmRssMeter:: start() 453: Could not find pid, can not collect vmrss data
2023-05-08 19:40:34.077  1314-1314  vendor.qti...or.service pid-1314                             E  +++++aac richtap stop enter
2023-05-08 19:40:34.077  1314-1314  vendor.qti...or.service pid-1314                             E  +++++aac richtap stop success
2023-05-08 19:40:34.079  1314-3907  AacRichTapConfig        pid-1314                             E  get actuator vib_id:0
2023-05-08 19:40:34.179  1297-4121  ANDR-PERF-LM            pid-1297                             E  DependentServices: getServices() 97: Service Tracker HAL could not find Client Connections
```

Comment: Can you add more details like Kivy version, Android Studio version, etc.

Comment: Of course thanks:
Python version = 3.10.4
Kivy version = 2.1.0
Kivymd version = 1.1.1

I used sqlite3 and i added it in the requirements and and the additional extension in the buildozer.sec file